# How to check collisions between 15 object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have 15 objects of the .fbx format. I always display them randomly. Here is the code

```
  for (let i = 0; i <15; i ++) {
  object = loadObj ('./ models / bump.fbx');
  object.position.set (randPos (), randPos (), randPos ());
  object.scale.set (randScale (), randScale (), randScale ());
  object.rotation.set (randRotation (), randRotation (), 
  randRotation ());
  object.name = "Object" + i;

   objects.add (object);
  }
```

I need to display them so that they do not intersect. How to check intersections? If there is an intersection between objects, look for a new position.

As a result, I need to get 15 randomly located objects that do not intersect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check collision (20 objects) in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458943/how-to-check-collision-20-objects-in-three-js)

Comment: This question mostly relates to mathematics, not specifically to Three.js. Some advice was given in the question, mentioned by Mugen87, about using of bounding boxes or bounding spheres of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by remembering already generated position of other objects in some place e.g. in array. And when you generate new position you check if it covers already created, if so regenerate new position